# SQL Server 2008 Indexes for a relatively large table ( 700.000 rows )

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have here a relatively big table with 700.000 records that I use a lot. I have two indexes on this table, Index1 is Orders and Index2 is DB_YEAR.

The selects I do in this table are like this

```
select * 
from bigtable 
where Order=:Order and DB_YEAR=:DB_YEAR
```

Now this is quite fast, but I was thinking about speeding it up even more. I could use another 3rd Index Archived which could divide this table into 10.000 records with Archive 0 and the rest with Archive 1 .

My question is if I add this third index to this 700.000 row table. And do a select like this:

```
select * 
from bigtable 
where Order=:Order and DB_YEAR=:DB_YEAR and Archive=0
```

will it be faster? Will SQL only locate the 10.000 records first and then look there for the `Order` and `DB_YEAR`?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends. It depends on the data, how the database engine assumes things would be faster, this and that. Only way to know is to try. But you might try a combined index if you’re always querying with those two columns instead of two separate indexes.

Comment: A filtered index containing both columns, with a filtered of archive=0 would probably be quickest. There are many options and approaches for indexing.

Comment: I think the fastest and smallest index for your query is a clustered index on Order and DB_YEAR and Archive. Even if you just have the Order and DB_YEAR columns in your clustered index it will still be faster than your current two separate indexes.

Comment: A filtered index would be smaller.

Comment: So the highest speed when using both Order and DB_YEAR I get with a Index which has both Order and DB_YEAR.
If I look after Order and have only this one INDEX it will still be very fast. 

But if I look for DB_YEAR it will be damn slow because of full table scan .

Another question :

If I have both single indexes one for Order and one for DB_YEAR.
And a third index which has both Order and DB_YEAR ... it has no penalty or? It takes up a bit of HDD space but nothing more...

Comment: The two-column index approach is assuming you are always going to query with both DB_YEAR and Archive in your conditions. Also I think a clustered index is smaller than filtered index since it physically store the data in that order. I haven't tested this so its just my theory.